# MacBook Pro doesn't stop when I close the lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

It's a 13" late 2009 model and I never had this problem up until now. Also the stop action from the  menu doesn't seem to work.

(I have installed [Caffeine](http://itunes.apple.com/it/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12) but I don't think it's the problem because the macbook won't stop even if the application is closed.)

Comment: Do you mean "sleep" instead of "stop"?

Comment: My system language is italian, is the default action performed when closing the lid called "sleep"?

Comment: Yes, in English, it's called "sleep". I assumed you were doing a direct translation, so I didn't edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user account.  Log out of your current user and into that new user.  Close the lid or use the apple menu.

If it sleeps, it's an application running in your user account that's preventing sleep from happening.

If it doesn't, it's system wide, maybe even a hardware problem.

Need more information :)